# PHP: Need to convert imagemagick command to php script

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I use this command to batch modify images for a site. They need to be this size to suit the theme.

Now I also want to use these images in Facebook Ads, but they have to be resized. The command I use (which works fine) is:

```
for i in `ls -1 *.jpg`; do convert $i -fuzz 10% -trim +repage -resize 980x1200 -background white -gravity center -extent 980x1200 $i; done
```

Now I need to make a PHP script that does the same, but also returns the image as response.

I came up with the following:

```
<?php

/* Create the object and read the image in */
$im = new Imagick("image.jpg");

/* Trim the image with 10% fuzz */
$im->trimImage(10);

/* Repage */
$im->setImagePage(0, 0, 0, 0);

/* Resize */
$im->resizeImage(1200,628,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,0);

/* Add Borders*/
$im->setImageBackgroundColor('White');
$im->setGravity('Centre');
$im->setImageExtent(1200,628);

/* Output the image */
header("Content-Type: image/" . $im->getImageFormat());
echo $im;
?>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. All it does is return a black rectangle (which looks like the right dimensions as used in the script).

Comment: What does `print_r(Imagick::getVersion());` tell you?

Comment: You cannot simply `echo $im`. You should use `echo $im->getimageblob();`.

Comment: Both my echo and yours seem to work for me. Unfortunately it just returns a black rectangle in the correct dimensions. So I assume something is going wrong in the manipulations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First error I get when running this code:

> PHP Warning:  Imagick::setgravity() expects parameter 1 to be integer, string given in resize.php on line 18

Try using `imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER` instead.

Next issue, `Imagick::resizeImage()` and `Imagick::setImageExtent()` expect parameters in width, height order.

Finally, try setting a non-zero value like 1 for blur on `Imagick::resizeImage()` to resolve the black image issue.

I'm not sure how you are trying to get a border, but you may want to look at `Imagick::borderImage()`.

I don't know if that will solve all your problems, but it should get you a lot closer!

```
<?php

/* Create the object and read the image in */
$im = new Imagick("image.jpg");

/* Trim the image with 10% fuzz */
$im->trimImage(10);

/* Repage */
$im->setImagePage(0, 0, 0, 0);

/* Resize */
$im->resizeImage(628, 1200, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);

/* Add Borders*/
$im->setImageBackgroundColor('White');
$im->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);
$im->setImageExtent(628, 1200);

/* Output the image */
header("Content-Type: image/" . $im->getImageFormat());
echo $im;
?>
```

Comment: setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER) doesn't seem to change anything. It still errors on expecting an int

Comment: `Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER` is an integer. If it's not, you'd be getting other errors.

Comment: And you never did answer the question about ImageMagick version.

Comment: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2017-03-12

Comment: Actually, after restarting apache2, I get no errors. But it's still not working.

Comment: I think the output is working fine. It shows a black rectangle which has the correct dimensions. The original image is a picture

Comment: It's working after removing the Blur int from the resizing. I don't need blur but thought it was required so I set it to 0.

Comment: Interesting, I got the all-black output when it was set to 0 but it went away when I changed it to 1.

Comment: It also works while set to one. In fact, I changed it even though it worked without, because php was complaining about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139622/discussion-between-johnny538-and-miken32).

Answer (score 0):

you can run commands in php using " shell_exec(your command) ". Try once this may works for you.
Refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php