# How to print concave-top text on image using imagemagick in php

Tags: php, imagemagick, concave

I'm trying to print Concave Top text using imagemagick in php. I searched over internet and found a command line script at Fred's Imagemagick scripts website.

**Outline Concave-Top Text
Arguments:**

```
-t "SOME CONCAVETOP TEXT" -s outline -e concave-top -d 0.5 -f Arial -p 48 -c skyblue -b white -o black -l 1 -u lightpink
```

[image: Image from Fred's website]

Please help me in converting the command line script to php imagemagick script.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43129275/php-need-to-convert-imagemagick-command-to-php-script) may help.

Comment: Are you trying to convert the whole texteffect script or just this one command? If the former, that would take a lot of work. If the latter, it might be possible, but it would be easier in either case to simply call the script command using PHP exec(). But note that if you are going to use the script or any part of it for commercial purposes, you will need to contact the developer for licensing.

Comment: Hi @fmw42
I'm trying to convert the command line script to php. I want to print concave-top text on an image. Even the command line script is fine for me if I can copy the output to a variable instead of storing it somewhere and accessing it.
Thank you

Comment: Hello @TomAranda Thank you for providing me the reference link. Sorry but the link didn't provide me the required solution. Can you please give me some steps to use the output generated from imagemagick command line script to print it on other image.

Comment: `@Prashanth Kumar` WROTE: "Even the command line script is fine for me if I can copy the output to a variable instead of storing it somewhere and accessing it." If you want to use the script and output the image as base64 text that can be done by piping the output to a convert command to write to base64. Is that what you meant by a variable? Perhaps you can explain in a bit more detail what you want for the variable and want to do with the image generated by the script command. Please note that if the script is used in a commercial environment, it must be licensed.

Comment: CONTINUED: If you want to overlay the text onto another image, then just use the script command with a transparent background (-b none) and then composite it over the background image where you want. You can pipe the output of the script to a convert or composite command to do the overlay all within a PHP exec() call.